# Django Views does not pass value related to logged in user but passes data of all users

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to make a form with inline form, the main form has editable fields. One select field needs to get data of only logged in users.

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def createinvoice(request):
    new_formset=createinvoiceformset(instance=serviceinvoice())
    if request.method == 'POST':
        inv_form=createinvoiceform(data=request.POST)        
        if inv_form.is_valid():
            new_form=inv_form.save(commit=False)
            new_form.user=request.user
            new_formset=createinvoiceformset(request.POST,instance=new_form)
            if new_formset.is_valid():
                new_form.save()
                hero=new_formset.save(commit=False)
                for hero1 in hero:
                    hero1.user=request.user
                    hero1.save()
                return HttpResponse('Invoice created')
    else:
        inv_form=createinvoiceform()        
        inv_form.fields["invoice_receivable"].queryset=Receivables.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request,'account/createinvoice.html',{'inv_form':inv_form,'new_formset':new_formset})
```

To populate the select field with data linked to logged in user. I use

```
inv_form.fields["invoice_receivable"].queryset=Receivables.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

**This line of code do give data linked to logged in users only but if form gives some error, select field gets data of all logged in users.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the queryset in the `else` block, so it only occurs for `GET` requests.

You need to set the queryset for `POST` requests as well.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    inv_form=createinvoiceform(data=request.POST)
    inv_form.fields["invoice_receivable"].queryset=Receivables.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

One problem with this is that you have duplicated code. A better approach might be to override the form's `__init__` method to accept `user` as an argument, and set the queryset there:

```
class CreateInvoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(CreateInvoiceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["invoice_receivable"].queryset = Receivables.objects.filter(user=user)
```

Note that I've renamed the form to `CreateInvoiceForm`, which is the recommended style for Python classes.

You then need to pass the `user` to the form as a keyword argument whenever you initialize it, for example

```
inv_form = CreateInvoiceForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)
```

Comment: Please give an example of __init__ method. Learning django hardway, thanks to people like you, ready to help.

Comment: I've added an example